# JavaScript logical operators internals

Tags: javascript, boolean, logical-operators

While reading the JavaScript documentation I came across a [section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) that confused me:

"Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values; when they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value. The logical operators are described in the following table.

```
&& Operator: expr1 && expr2
```

(Logical AND) Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

```
|| Operator: expr1 || expr2
```

(Logical OR) Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false."

Let's say you have:

```
var a3 = false && true;
```

so taking into the consideration the rule for the "and" operator, the variable a3 should contain the value true since "false" cannot be converted to false.

Comment: False can be converted to false trivially, since it is already false.

Comment: Why can't `false` be converted to `false`? `false` is `false`.

Comment: True can be converted to false also. Therefore anything can be converted to false?

Comment: True can't be converted to false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The choice of words *"can be converted to false"* stems from JavaScript having *truthy* and *falsey* values.

All values can be converted to a *truthy* or *falsey* value.

`false` is falsey, so no type *conversion* as such would take place, but other values would convert to false, such as:

```
undefined, null, NaN, 0, ""
```

So the and statement would return `false` and not `true`, because `false` is already `false` and no conversion would be necessary.

Comment: I think you are right. The confusion resulted from a poor choice of words in the documentation. A better way it could have been put would've been, "returns expr1 if it is a false value; otherwise, returns expr2" in conjunction with the line, 'Examples of expressions that can be converted to false are those that evaluate to null, 0, the empty string (""), or undefined.'

Comment: @robertrocha—how expressions are converted to Boolean values is in [ECMA-262 §9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2). And it is important to distinguish that the value of the expression is converted to Boolean **only** for the sake of comparison, the returned value is the actual value of the expression (e.g. `null` converts to `false` for the comparison, but the value `null` is returned).